# When does a graph have a minimally strong orientation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs, orientation

Given an asymmetric relation $A\subseteq V^2$ a digraph $D=(V,A)$ is minimally strong *iff* $D$ is strongly connected and for all arcs $\alpha\in A$ the digraph $D−\alpha=(V,A\setminus\{\alpha\})$ is not strongly connected.

Now by [Robbins' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins%27_theorem) a graph has a [strong orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_orientation) iff said graph has an [ear decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition) iff said graph is $2$-edge connected. Thus clearly every graph with a minimally strong orientation will be $2$-edge connected, however it is easy to see that many such graphs do not have any minimally strong orientations. For instance [wheel graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) are $2$-edge connected, though no wheel graph has a minimally strong orientation. I can prove when a graph $G$ has a minimally strong orientation then we have the inequality $|V(G)|\leq |E(G)|\leq 2|V(G)|-2$ as well as $\delta(G)=2$ and $\chi(G)\leq 3$.